# Accessing Name value in Expression block

Tags: powershell, calculated-columns

Is there a way to get value of column Name for calculated column inside Expression block?
I want to add custom column to `Select-Column` but I don't want to repeat group name in Name and Expression parts to avoid typos. Neither using multiple variables is not clean way.

```
...,
@{Name="Administrators";Expression={Test-ADGroupMembership -User $_.sAMAccountName -Group "Administrators"}},
@{Name="Domain Admins";Expression={Test-ADGroupMembership -User $_.sAMAccountName -Group "Domain Admins"}},
@{Name="Enterprise Admins";Expression={Test-ADGroupMembership -User $_.sAMAccountName -Group "Enterprise Admins"}},
@{Name="Schema Admins";Expression={Test-ADGroupMembership -User $_.sAMAccountName -Group "Schema Admins"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

No - an `Expression` script block has no knowledge of its enclosing hashtable in the context of a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties), so it cannot query that hashtable's `Name` entry.

However, you can reduce the duplication by declaring the array of property names ahead of time and referencing it both in the `Name` and `Expression` entries:

```
$propNames = 'Administrators', 'Domain Admins', 'Enterprise Admins', 'Schema Admins'

... | Select-Object `
  @{Name=$propNames[0]; Expression={Test-ADGroupMembership -User $_.sAMAccountName -Group $propNames[0]}},
  @{Name=$propNames[1]; Expression={Test-ADGroupMembership -User $_.sAMAccountName -Group $propNames[1]}},
  @{Name=$propNames[2]; Expression={Test-ADGroupMembership -User $_.sAMAccountName -Group $propNames[2]}},
  @{Name=$propNames[3]; Expression={Test-ADGroupMembership -User $_.sAMAccountName -Group $propNames[2]}}
```

---

If you're feeling adventurous, you can automate the process of creating the hashtables:

```
$calcProps =
 ('Administrators','Domain Admins','Enterprise Admins','Schema Admins').ForEach({
  @{
    Name = $_
    Expression = [scriptblock]::Create(
      'Test-ADGroupMembership -User $_.sAMAccountName -Group "{0}"' -f $_
    )
  }
})

... | Select-Object $calcProps
```